# table won't allow me to append more than 2 cells

Tags: javascript, json

```
    function createTable(data_array){
        const billing_table_body = document.querySelector('#billing_progile_Table > tbody')

        

        //we loop through object array and have access to each individual JSON
        for(var i = 0; i<objarray.length;i++){
                console.log("data : ",objarray[i].profileName)
                
                //create row 
                const tr = document.createElement('tr'); //creating the row
                console.log('creating new row');

            
                
                //append individual tds
                const td = document.createElement('td')
                td.textContent = objarray[i].profileName//appends data from the json cell
                td.className = 'text_td';
                tr.appendChild(td);
               
                const td_two = document.createElement('td')
                td_two.textContent = objarray[i].cardemail
                td.className = 'text_td';
                tr.appendChild(td_two);

                const td_three = document.createElement('td')
                td_two.textContent = objarray[i].cardownername
                td.className = 'text_td';
                tr.appendChild(td_three);
                
                const td_four = document.createElement('td')
                td_two.textContent = objarray[i].cardnumber
                td.className = 'text_td';
                tr.appendChild(td_four);

               
                
                
                    
                //append whole row to tr
            billing_table_body.appendChild(tr); 
            }
                
        }
```

im trying to append the cells into the table with their data but the table won't allow me to do it and I need to write it like this because im trying to access specific objects of the json array. any help im new to JAVASCRIPT AND JSON

Comment: Where is `objarray` defined? Also, you are always adding the `text_td` class to the first one, instead of `td_wo`, `td_three` etc., and you are appending the `textContent` to `td_two` instead of `td_three` and `td_four`. You should create a reusable function or use a loop to avoid having to repeat code and mixing things up

Comment: thank you I did not see that I fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please stop adding row and cells with createElement() method...!

```js
const billing_table_body = document.querySelector('#billing_progile_Table > tbody')

function createRows(data_array) 
  {
  data_array.forEach(el => 
    {
    let newRow = billing_table_body.insertRow()
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = el.profileName
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = el.cardemail
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = el.cardownername
    newRow.insertCell().textContent = el.cardnumber

    newRow.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(td=>td.className='text_td')
    })
  }
```

Comment: Cool one. One suggestion: `['profileName', 'cardemail', 'cardownername', 'cardnumber'].forEach(prop => { const td = newRow.insertCell(); td.textContent = el[prop];  td.className='text_td'; });`

Comment: @blex Personally, I find that repeating the same class name on all TDs is an error, because css can do it very well by inheritance

Comment: True. But... you're already doing it, and you already have a `forEach` just for adding that class. So I thought taking this opportunity to also add the textContent was a way to avoid repeating the `textContent` lines

Comment: @blex I hesitated to put this `forEach` directly on `billing_table_body`, out of the first loop on `data_array.forEach`